# -SQL- Summing by other column value

Tags: sql, sum

I have the following columns:

```
merchant_id
euro
```

I would like to sum all euro records by `merchant_id` and only return the `total sum per merchant_id`.

So if have 3 records like:

```
euro  | merchant_id 
4     |    1
5.4   |    2  
2.5   |    1
```

The result should be:

```
euro  | merchant_id
 6.5  | 1
 5.4  | 2
```

How on earth do i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use group by  and sum them up.

```
SELECT SUM(euro) AS euro,merchant_id
FROM  table_name
GROUP BY merchant_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    merchant_id
    ,sum(euro)
from
    <your_table_name>
group by
    merchant_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by could be the solution:

```
    select merchant_id, SUM(euro) as total
    from <your_table>
    group by merchant_id
    order by merchant_id;
```

enjoy ;-)